# How can I reorder the menu on mobile navbar?

Tags: wordpress, wpbakery

I've tried reordering the menu with css "order: 1;" etc, but I cannot moove the hamburger button on the right.

In wordpress there is no way the edit the menu (I can just edit the link and logo image), and I guess I need to do it by code.

The website is: https://materassibifulco.it (look at the mobile version)

I need to make the cart icon the last one, and the hamburger menu the first.

Thank you very much! If you need more information just ask me

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the menu is placed with `position: absolute;` and it harder to align with simple `order:1;`
try this code it helps you

```
@media (max-width:767px){
   .header_mobile .octf-btn-cta {
      padding-right: 0;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
   }
   .mobile_logo {
      display: inline-flex;
      justify-content: center;
      width: 100%;
   }
   .mobile_logo a img {
        left: 0 !important;
    }
   .octf-header-module:nth-child(2) {
      display: none;
   }
   #mmenu_toggle {
    left: 0px;
   }
}
```

---

In inspector after this style it [looks like](https://prnt.sc/wbmr8v)

Comment: Oh that's great!!
I was trying to add so many codes to achieve it.